# Is it correct to use the Past Perfect Continuous with the time expression 'after'?

Tags: grammar, past-perfect

Is the sentence correct?

> After my cousin had been studying Nuclear Physics for six years, he couldn't find a job

I don't think I've ever seen the Past Perfect Continuous used in this case; it's always been the Past Perfect Simple.

Comment: Yes, it's unusual but it's fine. It may suit some contexts better. **After he had been slaving over his books the whole night, he fell asleep at his desk.**

Comment: **Despite having studied** Nuclear Physics for six years, my cousin couldn't find a job.

Answer (score 1):

"After I had been waiting for twenty minutes, the bus finally arrived" is OK.

Your example feels a bit odd, because if he was looking for a job he had presumably finished his studies and gained a qualification. The continuous tense suggests that the studies were still ongoing.